# How hard to negotiate new salary?

Tags: salary, job-offer

I'm currently in quite a low paid job, £34k as a senior .NET developer. I (stupidly) gave away my salary to a recruitment agency whilst applying for a new job. The salary range of this new job is £35k-55k, they are offering £40k but I have insisted on £45k-£46k (£45k is the median and is the market rate.)

I'm quite comfortable where I am and I've applied for four development jobs in my life and have never been rejected, so I'm quite confident that I can get a job at £45k elsewhere. However this company seems like a nice place to work, is close to home and has a lot of room for career development.

The recruiter is going to speak to the account manager on Monday. If they continue to low ball me then I'm thinking of just telling the recruiter that whilst a 32% increase might seem like a lot, I can always walk in to a different job on a similar salary but with a different recruiter that does not know my current salary.

Am I being a little too forthright here or is this an acceptable tactic?

Comment: Telling them you can go somewhere else is not a good negotiating tactic.

Comment: Just to clarify I meant tell the recruiter not the employer. Is it still a bad idea? Also I get the impression that the recruiter's commission is based on how close they can get my salary to the target of £40k instead of being a percentage of my agreed salary. (They seemed very against me asking for more money.)

Comment: Are you willing to walk away if they refuse to meet your offer.  If you are then good.  If want to accept 40k if they wont come up then accept it.  There is no magic trick to negotiation.  You tell them what you want.  They counter if that is not good enough you tell them no or vice versa.

Comment: @Paparazzi what is wrong with it?  It is the basic premise of BATNA.

Comment: Chad: to be honest I'm not sure. There is a bonus of up to 10% and apparently there's lots of room to progress. But I would take a refusal to budge on salary at all as a bad sign and would probably say no. Also why the down vote?

Comment: If u don't plan to move then why post a question

Comment: "they are offering £40k but I have insisted on £45k-£46k" - isn't this already a form of negotiation? You politely told them your minumum. Now you have only to wait and see if they are willing to meet it. If they don't, you should be prepared to turn them down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Career decisions should always be taken keeping long term perspective in mind. And salary is just one criteria for selecting a job. There are other factors like, company, work culture, learning, growth, work life balance and more. Give a weightage to all the factors, and then evaluate how much difference the monetary factor is going to make.

Other things being equal, in my opinion you can easily make out for those extra pounds (quiet possibly more) if the job offer adds rich learning and that experience to your profile. In most of the cases, its proven that long term investments reap more.

While negotiating, one should not sound like money is the only important factor that count and you can move elsewhere if the offer does not meet your expectation. Instead you should try to convince the employer by highlighting your knowledge and skills and the value addition that you make to the organization. This would give an impression that you are interested for the opportunity and chances would be better then. Sometimes the companies have a capping for a certain level of experience and role, in such case it would be difficult to cross the boundary.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I should find out in a couple of hours and I'll let you know what the outcome is.

Answer (score 1):

In the United States, the only way I've gotten a large raise was by taking on new responsibility.  Here, I cannot expect to get more just because other companies offer more or because they offered a new hire more money than I make.

Negotiating based upon a better offer elsewhere **poisons** the environment.  All the employers I know in the U.S.A. will merely be offended and tell you to take the other job.

In the end, you need to weigh the salary and the intangible benefits of the job against some other option.

- If you begin to leave work early, resent your work, daydream at work, find ways to do things other than your 'assignments', it is definitely time to seek out a new job.
- If you are happy with the challenges and thrilled to work with your colleagues, that is rare and don't go looking someplace else.
- If you're wondering if there are better challenges out there for you, take a look are casually and see if the 'grass is really greener' in another pasture.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, it's relatively common to ask for more over here. I've just spoken to the recruiter and apparently the upper bound is basically just to attract people to the job. So I said they must get a lot of people asking why their offers are so low and wanting more money.